# why need of "println(char[] x)" when there is already "println(Object x)" - java

Tags: java, arrays, char

I was reading about println function and I came across that there is **println(char[ ] x)** as well as **println(Object x)**
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(char[])

*My question is that:* As arrays in java are object so what is the need to **specifically** overload println() with char[] whereas rest arrays like int[] etc. uses the **println(Object x)** overloaded function.

Comment: Probably because it is impossible to implement `toString()` on a `char[]`  i.e. `char` is different than `Character`.

Comment: You can try `Object o = "abc".toCharArray(); System.out.println(o);` to see what happens if you pass the array to the object overload.

Comment: Did you try both to see the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are implemented differently.

```
println(Object)
```

will (after checking for `null`, etc), call the parameter's `toString()` method and display the result of it.

The `toString()` method of an array is not useful: it will give you the array type and the hashcode of the array. So the overloaded form gives a more useful implementation in the case of a `char[]` parameter.

Note that, with most object types, the `toString()` method can be overridden (so overloading the `println(...)` method for every possible type is not necessary (or possible...). However, the `toString()` method cannot be overridden for arrays, so there is benefit to overloading `println` in this case.

Comment: I still can't get what is the benefit of it. Suppose this func "println(char[] x)" is not present then we can still get the content of char[] by using for-loop, can convert it to string using valueOf(), even get the array type and hashcode etc... just like any other array type i.e int[], float[] etc..

Comment: @Adi The benefit is you don't have to write the `for` loop, or do the conversion, every time you want to display an array of `char`s. (I think it also does null checks, so you don't have to do those yourself either.) You could make the same argument that you don't really need `println(int)` etc (you can use `Integer.toString(...)`) or even `println(Object)` (use `println(obj == null ? "null" : obj.toString())`) either. They just make it more convenient to use.

Comment: thanks for your explaination and helping me out in my doubt

Comment: @Adi Off-topic: you mean "question", not "doubt". "Question" and "doubt" can be synonymous when used as verbs ("I question that..." is more or less the same as "I doubt that..."), but they have quite different meanings as nouns (a "doubt" is a suspicion that something is wrong; a question is just something you ask).

Comment: *helping in my ques.

Answer (score 3):

```
 println(Object x)
```

if you use it to print a char array (the char array is an object), it won't print the content but the objectClass@hashcode style. You can test it yourself to see the exact output.

Comment: yeah that's rite I know and that is the case with other array type... but that's where doubt arises that, why have println in only overloaded with char[] and not with other array types

Comment: because most probably you will print strings and char arrays as a part of string algorithms. It's straight forward to implement on one line. As if you want your array objectS printed- that is more custom.. do you want them on one line? or coma separated.. non of the compiler's business

Answer (score 0):

Because it prints the char array as a string and otherwise prints in object form, and seeing the contents may be more convinient. You can try casting it to object first and see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Because `print/ln(char[])` handles the actual printing of characters, `toString()` of the array object itself still provides the usual type+hash output, regardless of being an array of characters

```
char c[]={'a','b','c'};
Object o=c;
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(c.toString());
System.out.println(o); // *
System.out.println(o.toString());
```

The * thing is interesting (and this is why I post at all, since the rest is already there in other answers) because it demonstrates that Java has single dispatch: the actual method to be invoked is decided in compilation time, based on the declared type of the argument(s). So it does not matter that o is a character array in runtime, in compilation time it seems to be an `Object`, and thus `print/ln(Object)` is going to be invoked for it.